# Comparing multiple columns in two pandas dataframes of different lengths

Tags: python, dataframe, comparison

I have two dataframes containing datetime columns. One contains the exact time of an event, and the other contains 2 columns with the start and end times of audio recordings. I want to match the event times with the corresponding recording - so, wherever the event time is greater than the start time and less than the end time.
I have tried:

```
for index, row in event.iterrows():
    for index, row in audio.iterrows():
        if event['datetime'] >= audio['startdt'] and event['datetime'] <= audio['enddt']:
```

and

```
for i in event['datetime'] >= audio['startdt'] and event['datetime'] <= audio['enddt']:
```

but these do not work as apparently the dataframes must be of the same length. (ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare). So, how can I make this comparison? I have seen several posts regarding similar situations but haven't found anything that doesn't rely on exact matching.